# synchronize data between local machine and database server machine

Tags: c#, sql-server

Could anybody tell me how can i synchronize from a local machine to sql server machine.

I have a simple local c sharp winform application with same database schemma as the sql server machine.

For example when user insert one new record in  my Intemsaleline table the record should insert to local machine and server machine and same for delete or update.

what should i do to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: you have your own C# Program and DB on your PC and when you do any action remote machine Database should be updated along with your own DB right?

Comment: If I understood this properly, you have one central SQL Server instance in the main office and many local SQL Server instances located in each branch? Branches update data locally and you want this data synchronized with the main office? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

We use Database to get the Unique behaviour from everywhere.

So you can maintain your Database somewhere in your Network(LAN) and connect to that Database from your C# code by providing Connection String as below:

**Example:**
Remote Machine Name: `RemoteSQLServer`

```
String ConnectionString="Data Source=RemoteSQLServer;Intitial Catalog=databsename;uid=DBusername;password=DBpassword;Integrated Security=True;";
```

so whenever you connect to your `Database` located in remote machine using above Connection String, all `Database` actions like `insert`,`update`,`delete`,`select` will be triggered on/from the `Server` machine Database.

**Connection String in Internet**:
Remote Machine IP : 161.85.29.11 (IP Address of remote machine where Database server is available)

```
 String ConnectionString="Data Source=161.85.29.11;RemoteSQLServer;Intitial Catalog=databsename;uid=DBusername;password=DBpassword;Integrated Security=True;";
```

Comment: my customer is a retail store system. with the main office and many branches in different provinces. in the main office we have a sql server machine and in each branch we have local machine. the local machine connect to the sql server machine through internet(not a LAN network). what is the connection string to connect from my local machine to the sql server machine in main office.

Comment: please let me know if you need anything more.